# How I can sort matrix according to both the first row and the third row as in the example?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

How I can sort `M` according to both the first row and the third row as in the following example:

```
M = [25 30 34 25 25 50 30 34
      3  4  8 11 99 58  3  4
     45 25 11 63 55 41 28 44]
```

the desired result:

```
Ms = [25 25 25 30 30 34 34 50
       3 99 11  4  3  8  4 58
      45 55 63 25 28 11 44 41]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) and just transpose twice (i.e. before and after) to effectively make it a "sort*columns*":

```
Ms = sortrows(M',[1,3])'
```